# Obtener lista que le mando al Adapter dentro del Viewholder

Tags: java, android

Me comentaron que es la practica ideal utilizar el OnClick dentro del ViewHolder, pero si con el OnClick debo utilizar los valores dentro de la lista que utilizo en el Adapter, ¿Como puedo obtener la lista? 
Acabo de pasar la lista a estatico , pero siento que esta mal hacerlo.

¿Esta mal hacerlo asi?, ¿Que otra manera hay?

Comment: Con getAdapterPosition() puedes obtener la posición que hace referencia al ítem, lo puedes usar para referirte dentro del array o lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La buenas prácticas indican que es mejor hacerlo a la asignación del `ViewHolder` y con la función `getAdapterPosition()` puedes obtener la posición al pulsar el elemento, así puedes obtener los datos con `tu_lista[posición]` o `tu_lista.getItem(posición)`

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    Context mContext;
    ImageView ivPhoto;
    TextView tvTitle;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mContext = view.getContext(); //obtener el context si se necesita más adelatne
        ivPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);

        ivPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "viewClick on " + mTitle.getText() + " position " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Aquí puedes recuperar datos tu_lista[getAdapterPosition()]
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Computar el click

El contenedor padre es el `itemView`

**En cualquier elemento**
Se debe asignar la escucha de la pulsación al contenedor padre `itemView` si el contenador padre es un `layout` como `LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout` etc..
se debe asignar el atributo `android:clickable="true"` para que pueda recibir el click.

Para una pulsación simple:

`itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()...`

Para una pulsación larga:

`itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()...`

**Cada elemento por separado**
Si en la vista queremos que si pulsan sobre la imagen se debe computar algo como el icono `favorito`

`ivPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()...`

Comment: ¿Sabes por que no me funcionaba? , porque mi Viewholder era estatico , crei que debia ser estatico para siempre funcionar, ¿Cual es la diferencia entre un Viewholder estatico y uno no estatico?  No se supone que es una buena practica tenerlo estatico, si esta estatico no puedo acceder a mTitle

Comment: No ser demasiado de Java, pero mi experienca depende de donde declares el adapter, si lo añades como una subclase de tu MainActivity te dice que debe estar estatico, pero si lo defines fuera en un archivo no

Comment: ¿Por que cambiaste el itemView.set... por ivPhoto?

Comment: si pones el itemView haces referencia a todo el cojunto es a dir a cada elemento en general y si especificas un elemento en concreto solo haces referencia a el, si tienes que se muestra logo, nombre y quieres que todo sea clickeable por igual itemView